# Modify the value of global class instance

Tags: c++, class, global

I have this class definition:

```
class event {
 public:
 wstring type;
 int pos;
 int sen;

 event(const string &t) : type(util::string2wstring(t)) {}
 ~event() {};
```

};

and the global variable:

```
list<event> events;
```

This variable was initialize in one function and after that I want to modify differents values of this events like:

```
for(auto ei : events) {
    ei.pos = (*w).get_position();
    ei.sen = sen;
    cout << "pos: " << ei.pos << " in sentence " << ei.sen << endl;
    ++w;
    ++sen;
}
event ei = events.front();
cout << "pos2: " << ei.pos << " in sentence2 " << ei.sen << endl;
```

Then the first cout print the correct values of the new pos and sen but the second (outside the for scope) print the oldest values.

If I print the values in other function the oldest values are printed.

I think that the problem is no reference access to the global variable but is it true?

And the most important, how can I fix it?

Thanks for your time,

Regards.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It is not true. I debug my program and i discover the problem with the no reference access. See the answer to see my problem. :)

Comment: Go for the [MCVE] then.

Comment: Please investigate _all_ uses of `auto`. As it stands, `ei` is a _copy_ of your vector's element, so when you change it, nothing changes in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ei` in your [range-for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is a *value* and not a reference. That means it is a copy of the element in the container, and modifying a copy of course does not modify the original.

To use references you need to specify it:

```
for(auto& ei : events) { ... }
//      ^
// Note ampersand here
```

Comment: was about to answer lol

Comment: Yes! That works. Thank you so much :)